# how to call a C .dll from C#?

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling

I have tried to call the C struct from C#, but I failed to make it work.
My struct define in C is as follow:

```
struct GHX{
    double output[28];
    int val;
};
```

And a function that I’m using to calculate the output is

```
__declspec(dllexport) void GHXfunction(
    double *XIN, double *parameter, 
    int mode, int hour, GHX *result)
{ 
    /*...*/
}
```

In C#,
I tried the following method.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GHX
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 28)]
    public double[] output;
    public int val;
}
[DllImport("GHXDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GHXfunction", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GHXfunction(
    IntPtr XIN, IntPtr parameter, int mode, 
    int hour , ref GHX result);
```

So far, I believe that everything is OK, because someone from stackoverflow has the same problem as me.
Then, I just test a simple scenario as follow.

```
static void Main()
{
    IntPtr XIN= IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr Par=IntPtr.Zero;
    int mode=1;
    int hour=0;
    GHX test = new GHX();
    GHXfunction(XIN, Par, mode, hour, ref test);
}
```

It then till me that 
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Does anyone have idea about it?
Thanks.

Edit, I actually don't know how does IntPtr work. So I guessed IntPtr.Zero will return memory location with 0, maybe i was wrong.

In my original C code I call the function like this

```
double par[42], xin[5];
ptrxin = &xin[0];
ptrpara = &par[0];
struct GHX result;
GHXfunction(ptrxin, ptrpara, 0, 0,result);
```

I dont know how to call the function in C# with the pointer input.
Thanks.

Working code:
Basing on Ben's suggestion. I can call the struct in C#.

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct GHX
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 28)]
        public double[] output;
        public int val;
    }


    [DllImport("GHXDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GHXfunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void GHXfunction(double[] XIN, double[] parameter, int mode, int hour,ref GHX result);


    static void Main()
    {
        double result;
        double[] XIN= new double[5];
        double[] Par = new double[42];
        int mode = 1;
        int hour=0;
        GHX test = new GHX();
        GHXfunction(XIN, Par, mode, hour,ref test);
        result = test.output[0];

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you can pass *IntPtr.Zero* to *XIN* and *Par* ?

Comment: Not sure! I don't know how does IntPtr work in C#~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C type of `double*` should be translated as either

```
ref double
```

or

```
double[]
```

Since your comments say those are arrays, try:

```
[DllImport("GHXDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GHXfunction(double[] XIN, double[] parameter, int mode, 
                                      int hour , ref GHX result);
```

P/invoke will take care of pinning the array and passing the address of the first element.

Comment: Thanks~ But in my C code, I read those *XIN, like this `double par[42]; for (i = 0; i < 42; i++)
 {
  parameter[i] = *par;
  par++;
 }` . Does it work for your method?

Comment: @user3745869: That's not even legal C.  You can't assign to an array name.  Anyway, what you showed in your question is passing the address of the first element, and that is exactly what the C# I showed will do.

Comment: Ben, Thanks, You are right. It works now. Thank you very much~~~  When I wrote this code, I am a newbie in C, and it is just 3 month ago. I knew the code looks like creepy, but it work.